# Auto populating the fields in lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button, detail-page

We have a detail page button in the Classic environment which opens a create new page of the custom objects with prefilled values in it. And the detauil page button looks like below

```
/a1U/e?CF00NU00000041q0K={!Opportunity.Account}
&CF00NU00000041q0K_lkid={!Opportunity.AccountId}
&CF00NU00000041q0U={!Opportunity.Contact__c}
&CF00NU00000041q0U_lkid={!Opportunity.ContactId__c}
&00NU00000042LoX={!Opportunity.Id}
&retURL={!Opportunity.Id}
```

But when I click on the button in lightning it doesn't auto populate the field values in the create new custom object page. How can this be approached in the lightning conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature will become available in Lightning in [Spring '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_lex_navigate_to_record_dfv.htm). From the linked release notes:

> How: To construct a custom button or link that launches a new record with prepopulated field values, use this sample formula:

```
/lightning/o/Account/new?defaultFieldValues=
    Name={!URLENCODE(Account.Name)},
    OwnerId={!Account.OwnerId},
    AccountNumber={!Account.AccountNumber},
    NumberOfEmployees=35000,
    CustomCheckbox__c={!IF(Account.SomeCheckbox__c, true, false)}
```

Until the release of Spring '20, you'd have to make do with Quick Actions using Predefined Field Values.

Comment: Thanks for the update, is there any way we can do this through VisualForce Page without the Quick Action?

Comment: When Spring '20 is released, yes.

Comment: The issue is that the Custom Object that I am trying is not in the list of the Target Object in the Quick Action creation even though there is a lookup relation ship between them

Comment: @DavidReed I tried following the answer and create a new URL button but it isnt working as expected https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400655/pass-the-related-record-id-through-the-url-hacking can you please help