# Pass the related record ID through the URL hacking

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, custom-button, related-list, urlhacking

I have a two custom object Sample and Sample detail. Sample detail has a lookup relationship to the Sample record. And both the records have lookup relationship to the Case.

[image]

When I create a Sample Detail record from the related list. I need to pull case that is in the Sample to the Sample Details automatically, so I created a custom URL List button

```
/lightning/o/Sample_Detail__c/new?defaultFieldValues=Sample__c={!Sample__c.Id},Case__c={!Sample__c.Case__c}
```

Trying this way I can see just Sample ID getting populated but dont see the Case field at all in the Sample Detail create new page. I even tried encoding `=` still that didnot work

```
 /lightning/o/Sample_Detail__c/new?defaultFieldValues=Sample__c%3D{!Sample__c.Id},Case__c%3D{!Sample__c.Case__c}
```

How can I pass the related record ID through the URL hacking method here. Any help is greatly appreciated I am kind of stuck here

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/342100/2602 for one solution

Comment: @cropredy I viewed the answer but it isnt populating the associated record ID from the parent. Here Case Id from the Sample isnt passed. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: did you use the formula field approach?

Comment: @croperdy No not all the time the CaseId on the SampleDetails would be the same as the CaseID on Sample.. There are sampledetail records that exists without Sample